# .NET Core 2.0 Web API Azure endpoint not available

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have deployed a Service App on Azure but when I access the website I get the following error:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

When call the endpoint locally it returns the right response. Here's the local url - http://localhost:52261/api/token

I'm calling the following url for Azure deployed service:
http://[azure-api-url]/api/token

Comment: How did you deploy it? First things first, make sure all files are there, including web.config. Open Kudu console and browse to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`.

Comment: I renamed the projects and files before publishing. So I created a new project and moved related code to the new one and published it. And that fixed the issue.